# StackExchange™ MultiCollider SuperDropdown™ predicted my future!

Tags: bug, status-completed, global-inbox

I posted a comment on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8816717/jquery-get-id-of-same-class-and-add-to-array.

The question's author posted a comment to somebody else a minute **before** my own comment; yet, the StackExchange™ MultiCollider SuperDropdown™ got notification about it:

[image: screenshot]

Is it future predicting, or did it consider my close vote (me being the last) as sort of comment?

Comment: I didn't get notified about this comment... but there is a space between the `@` and `Felix`.

Comment: @Felix because he had blank space after the `@` - that's not the point. :) - lol you were faster than me.

Comment: Haven't you heard? It's one of the great new features of version 12.0 of the StackExchange™ MultiCollider SuperDropdown™, of which you're a secretly-chosen beta tester!

Comment: I thought it might be worth mentioning it, but if it's not I will just go and be crazy somewhere else :P ;)

Comment: Not bad for something that was originally designed as a shower curtain.

Comment: @Felix you think that blank `@` is sort of "joker"? hmm...

Comment: Yeah, maybe it's a secret `notify all people` thingy thing @ all.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Hehe, nice catch. Fixed in the next build. Here's what happened:

1. Felix Kling voted to close as a dupe; thus the automatic "possible duplicate of…" comment was posted.
2. Other users voted to close, and eventually the question was closed and the auto-comment removed.
3. denys281 (the OP) posted the comment that (later) ended up in your Inbox. He posted this comment shortly after step 2 (probably before refreshing the page to see that the question was closed and the comment gone).
4. You posted your *If you "don't really understand the answers"…* comment.
5. The OP edited their comment.

We don't keep a revision history of comments, so I don't know what was changed in step 5, but it doesn't really matter. In particular the whole question of `@ Felix` vs. `@Felix` vs. no `@` at all is not significant here.

What matters is that when a comment is edited, the check for "who is this in reply to" is re-done. This re-check (and here's the bug) considered all comments that existed *at the time of editing*, even if they were posted *after* the edited comment was originally posted.

Thus that check saw that there was a comment from you (step 5), and the edited comment was from the post owner. No other comments were present (step 2). Thus the "conversation between post owner and only one other person" logic took effect, making the comment a reply to *you* (the "other person").

This missing "only consider comments posted before this one was *originally* posted" check is added in the next build.

Comment: Nice little bug.. I almost feel sorry for crunching it! :)